# Copied folder not found

Tags: powershell

```
$adobe = "C:\Acrobat Pro DC"
$computer = Read-Host -Prompt "Computers Name"

$destination = "\\$computer\c$\temp"

Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $adobe -Destination $destination

Enter-PSSession $computer
Test-Path "c:\temp\Acrobat Pro DC\Adobe Acrobat"

Set-Location "c:\temp\Acrobat Pro DC\Adobe Acrobat"
Start-Process "install_acrobat.bat"
exit
```

Above is the current code I am using.  The `Test-Path` keeps returning false even though the folder does exist, and the `Set-Location` says the folder does not exist either.  What am I missing?

Comment: does the account you are using for this have permission to see that location? your previous access what thru the hidden `c$` share ... the permissions on those are not _required_ to be the same ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a script file then the commands after `Enter-PSSession` do not run in that session as explained on [MS social technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e89b957-ff5b-42c4-b107-d7e18752fcf1/enterpssession-within-a-script?forum=winserverpowershell).